# iTextSharp: Extracted CMYK Image is inverted

Tags: c#, .net, image, pdf, itext

I have been using itextsharp to extract text from a PDF and I wanted to extract all the images, which may be grayscaled JPGs, CMYK JPGs, and PNGs (according to the itextsharp filter). When I extract the images, gray JPGs and PNGs show correctly. However, CMYK JPGs appear weird, like their colors were inverted after extraction. Here is my code:

```
internal class ImageRenderListener : IRenderListener
{
    #region Fields

    List<System.Drawing.Image> images = new List<System.Drawing.Image>();

    #endregion Fields

    #region Properties

    public List<System.Drawing.Image> Images
    {
        get { return images; }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods

    #region Public Methods

    public void BeginTextBlock() { }

    public void EndTextBlock() { }

    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();
        PdfName filter = (PdfName)image.Get(PdfName.FILTER);

        //int width = Convert.ToInt32(image.Get(PdfName.WIDTH).ToString());
        //int bitsPerComponent = Convert.ToInt32(image.Get(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT).ToString());
        //string subtype = image.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).ToString();
        //int height = Convert.ToInt32(image.Get(PdfName.HEIGHT).ToString());
        //int length = Convert.ToInt32(image.Get(PdfName.LENGTH).ToString());
        //string colorSpace = image.Get(PdfName.COLORSPACE).ToString();

        /* It appears to be safe to assume that when filter == null, PdfImageObject 
         * does not know how to decode the image to a System.Drawing.Image.
         * 
         * Uncomment the code above to verify, but when I've seen this happen, 
         * width, height and bits per component all equal zero as well. */
        if (filter != null)
        {

            System.Drawing.Image drawingImage = image.GetDrawingImage();
            var DimParams = renderInfo.GetImageCTM();

            string extension = string.Empty;

            if (filter == PdfName.DCTDECODE)
            {
                extension += PdfImageObject.ImageBytesType.JPG.FileExtension;

            }
            else if (filter == PdfName.JPXDECODE)
            {
                extension += PdfImageObject.ImageBytesType.JP2.FileExtension;
            }
            else if (filter == PdfName.FLATEDECODE)
            {
                extension += PdfImageObject.ImageBytesType.PNG.FileExtension;
            }
            else if (filter == PdfName.LZWDECODE)
            {
                extension += PdfImageObject.ImageBytesType.CCITT.FileExtension;
            }

            /* Rather than struggle with the image stream and try to figure out how to handle 
             * BitMapData scan lines in various formats (like virtually every sample I've found 
             * online), use the PdfImageObject.GetDrawingImage() method, which does the work for us. */

            Images.Add(drawingImage );
        }

    }

    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) { }

    #endregion Public Methods

    #endregion Methods
}
```

I think that somehow the problem should be in the way the stream is decoded, but I do not understand how to fix this.
Thanks to any who has an idea.

Here is the extracted image (updated):

[image]

and here is a link to the PDF
http://docdro.id/ZoHmiAd

Comment: Can you link to a sample PDF with that issue?

Comment: I just added them.

Comment: Why do you think the image is *inverted*? I see a fully black image. Inverted CMYK images are well know; it's an old bug in Adobe Photoshop that now has become a de-facto industry standard.

Comment: Sorry, I reuploaded the image. I don't know what happened when saving the image, so I took a screenshot.

Comment: I haven't worked with CMYK and .Net for a while now but it used to be either not supported at all or you had to dance a lot. According [to this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19363265/231316) older thread it still might not be supported.